# Calibrating a model against real observations

Tags: climate

I have a dataset consisting of rasters of daily high and low dry-bulb air temperatures in the continental US, one raster per day. This dataset was produced by an ensemble of different climate models all set to forecast the years 2011 through 2049 under an RCP8.5 scenario.

Now that some time has passed, I have six complete years of actual daily temp data that I can compare to the model by sampling the model rasters at the locations of the stations at which the actual temp observations were made. My goal is to see if there were some calibration I could apply to the model data over the overlapping years, starting with the assumption that such a calibration would take the form of a scale and shift (i.e., X'=aX+b for some (a,b)).

My process was to establish an initial (a,b) - a=1 and b=0 would be the "null case," i.e., no calibration - compute the sum of the square of the differences between the high temps and low temps at that (a,b) and at the eight points surrounding (a,b) formed by adding/subtracting small intervals to each, selecting as the new (a,b) the location in the a-b plane that produced the least sum, and repeating this process until my (a,b) produced the lowest of the nine results. So picture a 3D space with (a,b) as the "floor" plane and a surface above it. Here is an actual computed result for all of the year 2011:

[image]

My hope was that the "walk" process could be started at some point and would arrive at a general minimum so the resulting (a,b) would be calibration parameters I could apply to the entire dataset in the interest of making more accurate predictions about related phenomena, but what I found was that any walk would roll down that trough and stop pretty much wherever it rolled down to. Initially I thought the surface formed an elliptical paraboloid, but it's not - I don't know what it's called, but it's just a parabolic sheet, as though made by a parabola translating across the a-b plane. So it doesn't have *one* minimum, but a horizontal line of minima.

My question is, where do I go with this next? I have two ideas: 1) challenge my assumption of X'=aX+b and simplify it to either X'=aX or X'=X+b 2) Rotate the coordinate system into some a' and b' such that the minima line is parallel to one of the a axis and the b axis and therefore one of the rotated coordinates can simply be eliminated. Could I make a more useful assumption than a calibration of X'=aX+b? Is there a better way I could be going about this?

NOTE: My intended application for this dataset is making predictions about future energy consumption in buildings and therefore I planned to convert my high/low temp rasters and convert them into daily heating/cooling degree day rasters using the NOAA degree day formula (the UK Met Office formula is a little more involved; it will produce non-zero HDDs and non-zero CDDs on the same day whereas the NOAA formula will not). Another thing I can do is forget about calibrating the temps and try to calibrate the HDDs and CDDs in a similar fashion; I don't really care about the temps themselves.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you are implementing your own descent-optimization for linear regression. Is there a reason why you are not using available implementations? It might be the the case that the surface you got is due to a bug.

From the description of the problem, it seems that the classical linear regression is a good fit. If $T = \{t_1, ..., t_n\}$ are observed temperatures (lows, highs, or both), and ${\hat{T}} = \{\hat{t}_1, ..., \hat{t}_n\}$ are corresponding temperatures predicted by the model, simply regress $\hat{T} \sim T$ and you're done. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Chalk it up to not knowing any better; I just implemented in R what I was imagining in my head. I'm used to using lm() in R to obtain best-fit linear coefficients to datasets where I can presume a linear relationship between multiple inputs and an output and make a model for that relationship, i.e., generate best-fit (a,b,c) such that z=aw + bx + c, but what I saw myself trying to do was different although I can imagine how the approach could be adapted into what I'm trying to do.

Comment: By way of update, I just re-ran the analysis using X'=aX+b where X are modeled heating and cooling degree days and X' are observations of same and the surface is indeed convex and has one minimum that all walks arrive at (for 2011 a,b=0.9973,0.462). This isn't the same as correcting temps but comparing degree days derived from adjusted temps but I will attempt that also.

Comment: Another update: I improved my walk algorithm such that now it performs either three or five recalculations (the latter in the case of diagonal movement across the a,b plane) instead of nine every time and I obtain a nice walk that will terminate if I use small enough walk increments. For 2011 data I get (to use your nomenclature) That = 0.997844T + 0.45058. Again, this is acting upon heating and cooling degree days derived from the Tmax and Tmin of both the model and the observations.

Comment: Another update: I improved my walk algorithm such that now it performs either three or five recalculations (the latter in the case of diagonal movement across the a,b plane) instead of nine every time and I obtain a nice walk that will terminate if I use small enough walk increments. For 2011 data I get (to use your nomenclature) That = 0.997844T + 0.45058. Again, this is acting upon heating and cooling degree days derived from the Tmax and Tmin of both the model and the observations. In R I did this:

Comment: lntest.df<-data.frame(model=c(model_cdd,model_hdd), observations=c(obsv_cdd,obsv_hdd))
lmo<-lm(model~observations, data=lntest.df)

Comment: Running the above produces
Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-39.827  -0.461  -0.461   0.552  28.224 
Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.4611351  0.0014452   319.1   <2e-16 ***
observations 0.8286572  0.0001552  5340.8   <2e-16 ***
Residual standard error: 2.915 on 5972400 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8269, Adjusted R-squared:  0.8269 
F-statistic: 2.852e+07 on 1 and 5972400 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

Comment: If I'm interpreting the summary output correctly, it's saying that the correction I want is That =  0.8286572T +  0.4611351. Problem is, the least-squares value at (a,b)=(0.829,0.461) is below the paraboloid; no walk will encounter it. If I apply lm's (a,b) to the model HDDs or CDDs, the change from the model's original values is a lot more pronounced than the a,b from my walk makes.

Comment: There are too many details (and places to overlook something), so I'm not sure I will be much of a help. Things look correct overall, but if you are indeed minimizing the quadratic average difference in your descent, I would be very concerned about the result not matching the coefficients from `lm`.